# Draw SurfaceView from layout xml, Ask information about answer

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

I found the following answer

[Draw SurfaceView from layout xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203547/draw-surfaceview-from-layout-xml?answertab=active#tab-top)

It works GREAT. However,I cannot figure out how to call a method/function from the extended SurfaceDraw class.I couldn't figure out how to ask a question of a particular answer either.

It seems like the following code should work. However, no matter where I put it it generates a null value so i can't make a call to a method/function.

DrawingSurfaceView drawingsurface = (DrawingSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.DrawingSurfaceView);

DrawingSurfaceView.MyMethod();

I am so very close to accomplishing my goals.  Any help with this is issue is greatly appreciated.

I got it. I will post an anser when the system lets me.

Answer (score -1):

I moved:

```
DrawingSurfaceView drawingsurface = (DrawingSurfaceView)findViewById
  (R.id.DrawingSurfaceView);
```

to `onCreate()` and it started working.