# Compile error "incompatible types" in ViewGroup

Tags: android

This code is straight from a tutorial on the proper use for the camera in android devices. It seems that CameraPreview does not have the correct terms to be added to the view.

```
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;

mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
```

Searching the ViewGroup requirements and the SurfaceHolder.Callback which CameraPreview implements is accepted which is what makes me confused. I think I am not understanding this properly.

Checking the declaration of Camera Preview in:

```
private CameraPreview mPreview;
```

sends it (in a separate activity) to:

```
public class CameraPreview extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
```

However, doing the same for

```
mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
```

sends it here instead:

```
public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera){
    mCamera = camera;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}
```

Error message:

```
Error:(29, 25) error: incompatible types: CameraPreview cannot be converted to View
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
public class CameraPreview extends Activity...
```

and this

```
mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
```

Are incompatible.  **You must never create an instance of an Activity yourself**, as you will not be able to properly initialize it.  The only way to create a *working* Activity instance is to have the system do it for you - ie, but firing an Intent.

```
Error:(29, 25) error: incompatible types: CameraPreview cannot be converted to View
```

It extends Activity, while to be converted to a View it must extend View.

First decide if this class is going to be used as a View or as an Activity, and then write and utilize it in a way consistent with your choice - you cannot have it be one and masquerade as the other.

Comment: So I've been racking my brain over this since yesterday and I'm still confused. Attempting to change CameraPreview to extend View solves the problem but then I have problems with the AndroidManifest. Is there a particular way that CameraPreview needs to be added to the manifest once View is extended so that it will work because every time I try it tells me it is  assignable to 'android.app.Activity'.

Comment: No, you cannot make a View masquerade as an Activity any more than you can make an Activity masquerade as a View.  They are distinct object types with distinct roles.  Generally they are used in coordination, though typically an Activity will have *specific* knowledge of the Views while the Views will only have a handle to the Context of their owning Activity but no specific knowledge of its details programmed in.

Comment: If I can try and understand this properly, do you mean to say that it is unnecessary to add CameraPreview to the manifest because it is a View? How then will the application be able to access it from CameraActivity?

Comment: I removed the .CameraPreview from the xml I am now getting the error: myapplication.CameraPreview cannot be cast to android.view.SurfaceHolder$Callback.

This guy seems to be having a similar problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307832/organizing-methods-between-surfaceview-and-activity

Comment: Please start with a much simpler example to get an idea of how Activities and Views are supposed to interact.